# Can logint to remote server via SSH but cannot copy file via scp: Host key verification failed

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, scp

So I have set up with 3 VM running Ubuntu 20.04 server. What I am trying to do is copy a folder from machine 1 to machine 2 and then another folder from machine 1 to machine 3.

1. All machines have OpenSSH installed with the same sshd_config (custom port, password-only etc.)
2. On the command line I am able to login to any of machines 2 or 3 via the command `ssh -p XXX username@192.168.0.xxx`. Of course, it asks for the user password, but I can log in.
3. I have setup a cron to execute following command:
   `sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' scp -r -P PORT# /home/user/folder/ user@192.168.0.xxx:/home/user`

When executing for machine 2 everything is OK and the folder and its content is being copied. But when executing for machine 3 I get `Host key verification failed` which is odd, as I've done the same steps for each machine.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.: Both on machine 2 and 3, there is an indentical record in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Whose account is the cron job run under? is it `root` or `user`?

Comment: I'm running both cron as root because the folder I want to copy is under /root folder. But the 'target' user is not root.

Comment: Right - but it will determine whose home directory it looks in for the `known_hosts` file

Comment: But then, why I have success copying on machine 2 and get an error when copying on machine 3?

Comment: I don't know - perhaps you previously logged in to machine 2 from root and accepted its fingerprint?

Comment: Root login over ssh is forbidden in the sshd_config file. Moreover, just tried to copy a folder as a normal user (via cron again) and again get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not talking about root login over ssh - I'm talking about *being root* (or more specifically, having `$HOME` equal to `/root`) when connecting as `user@192.168.0.xxx`. Regardless, you could consider setting `StrictHostKeyChecking` more permissively to avoid the error.

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered something. I've tried rsync as root from machine 1 to copy over machine 2 and it worked. And thenn I confirmed that cron also works.